# MySQL convert different date formats to timestamp

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a log table, which has a timestamp column. The problem is, that the data written in it isn't a timestamp format. 
It's a string, and since there are logs from different parts of the World, the format is not consistent either.

To fix the problem, I added a **real timestamp** column, which is working correctly for new INSERTS, but there are a couple of thousand log entries where this column is **null** and the old timestamp column has the data.

Is there any MySQL function, that tries to convert these differently formatted date strings to a timestamp format?

I want to delete the old column at some point in time, but I need to make sure the old logs have a correct timestamp as well.

Comment: Why not read all rows having a NULL value for the real timestamp, convert the old timestamp of these records via your favourite programming language, then write the data back? Usually programming languages with their sophistication are more able to solve such a problem.

Comment: You need to investigate `str_to_date()`, possibly combining it with regular expressions.

Comment: PHP's `strtotime()` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)  is able to ingest all sorts of different date formats and emit standardized timestamps.   That might be worth investigating if you can't get MySQL's `str_to_date()` function to work. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)